# Why does the Audacity icon change in the launcher if the launcher icon size is adjusted?

Tags: launcher, icons, audacity

I noticed when I was fiddling with the launcher icon size that at a certain size the icon for Audacity changes. Does anyone know why this would happen?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Freedesktop Icon Theme Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) allows multiple images to be provided for a given icon name where the image chosen will depend on the size being requested.

Presumably, Audacity is providing multiple icons and this is the size at which the image choice changes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe becausethe two icons used are different.
I suggest that you check in your icon theme the differences between the icons for audacity in different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

The default icon was built for a small size and would not look good at larger sizes, so to fix this they use a higher resolution icon for the larger sizes.